# Adding environment variables using java program and able to see when I open environment tab from My Computer

Tags: java, windows

I want to write java program which adds environment variables and when I open environment tab from MyComputer,then I should be able to see that...

This is what I have tried,but it gives java.lang.unsupportedexception

Map env = System.getenv();
   env.put("abc", "pqr");

And One more try is below,it is not giving any error...But I can not see any value added when I open environment variables tabl`enter code here` from My Computer.But When i sysout "env" variable it gives me all paths including myone also...But I need same thing to be shwon in environment variables tab...

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","set");      
Map env = processBuilder.environment();
env.put("abc", "pqr");
```

Please help me guys...Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure that you tag your questions correctly. You're more likely to get an answer that way. I've retagged this for you - it was tagged as 'iPhone' for some reason.

Comment: Although System.getenv() returns a Map of the environment variables, it "Returns an unmodifiable string map view of the current system environment", so you can't call put() on it. You could try new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","set abc=pqr").start();

Comment: Sorry for that @RobinSummerhill...I will take care in future...

Comment: Sure @HighlandMark.I try that and then let u know...But thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. The first one is to call the Windows API to change/set the environment variable. You must look for the right Windows API function and call it from Java. However calling any Windows API from Java is a topic on its own.

The second way is to call the `setx.exe` program with the correct arguments to set environment variables. Check the manual of the `setx.exe` program how to use it (and when it is installed) to set your environment variables.

In both ways you obviously restrict your Java program to run on Windows systems only.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Progman.But I think in my case it will not work.Because it says that your windows should be genuine enough and mine is genuine.But what about my clients?So I think I shold find another option.Anyway thanks once again...